# Распечатка словаря в ООП

Tags: python, python-3.x

Никак не получается вывести словарь при начале программы. А так же количество контактов в словаре, вернее количество контактов выводится в 0. Подскажите пожалуйста почему так происходит?

```
import pickle


class Address:
    my_dict = dict()

    def __init__(self, key, value, fname, semail):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.fname = fname
        self.semail = semail

        Address.my_dict = dict()  # Открываем для записи.
        with open('my_dict.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.write(key)
            file.write(value)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.key = input('Введите имя: ')
        self.value = input('Введите адрес: ')
        Address.my_dict[self.key] = self.value
        if self.key in Address.my_dict:
            print('\nАдрес:', Address.my_dict)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.key = input('Введите имя для удаления: ')
        del Address.my_dict[self.key]  # Удаляем контакт.
        print('\nВ адресной книге: {0} контактов\n'.format(len(Address.my_dict)))
        for name, address in Address.my_dict.items():
            print('\nКонтакт: {0}, с адресом {1}.'.format(name, address))

    def change(self):
        self.key = input('Введите имя которое нужно изменить: ')
        del Address.my_dict[self.key]

        self.fname = input('Введите новое имя: ')
        self.semail = input('Введите новый адрес: ')
        Address.my_dict[self.fname] = self.semail
        if self.fname in Address.my_dict:
            print('\nАдрес:', Address.my_dict)

    def find(self):
        self.key = input('Введите имя для поиска: ')
        if self.key in Address.my_dict:
            print('Адрес: ', Address.my_dict[self.key])
        else:
            print('Такого имени не существует.')

    def loading():
        file = open('Book.data', 'rb')
        Address.my_dict = pickle.load(file)  # Помещаем объект в файл.
        file.close()

    loading = staticmethod(loading)

    def store():
        file = open('Book.data', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(Address.my_dict, file)  # Помещаем объект в файл.
        file.close()

    store = staticmethod(store)


r = Address('', '', '', '')
Address.loading()
running = True

while running:
    try:
        search = int(input('''Введите:
    1-Добавить контакт; 
    2-Удалить контакт;
    3-Изменить контакт;
    4-Найти контакт; 
    Для выхода их программы введите 5-Выход:'''))
    except ValueError:
        print('Выберте один из варантов.')
    else:
        if search == 1:
            r.__setitem__('', '')
            if len(Address.my_dict) == 100:
                print('Адресная книга переполнена, удалите 1 из контактов')
                r.__delitem__('')

        if search == 2:
            try:
                r.__delitem__('')
            except KeyError:
                print('Вы ввели не верное имя.')

            Address.store()

        if search == 3:
            try:
                r.change()
            except KeyError:
                print('Введите существующее имя с заглавной буквы.')

            Address.store()

        if search == 4:
            try:
                r.find()
            except KeyError:
                print('Введите существующее имя с заглавной буквы.')

        if search == 5:
            Address.store()
            running = False

        if len(Address.my_dict) == 0:
            running = False
```

Comment: Не используйте напрямую магические методы: `r.__setitem__('', '')`, `r.__delitem__('')`. У них есть прекрасные аналоги `r[''] = ''` и `r.pop('')` (или `del r['']`)

Comment: Всё, всем спасибо. Сам догадался. Сделал. Ну было после Address.loading() напечатать print(len(Address. my_dict)) и print(Address.my_dict)

Comment: А что они дают эти аналоги?

Comment: `А что они дают эти аналоги?` тот же результат сохраняя красивый синтаксис. Кроме того, магические методы (они так официально называются) просто не рекомендуются для ручного вызова. Раз, вы смогли разобраться, то добавьте, пожалуйста, ответ с проблемой и как ее решили :)

Comment: Я написал что и куда надо добавить. Или обязательно весь код писать?

Comment: Надо дополнить решением вопрос, например. Или написать ответ отдельно. Не все смотрят в комментарии.

Comment: Под вопросом есть поле для заполнения ответа. А то, что вы написали это комментарии и они не для ответов :) Да и, честно говоря, непонятно как печать словаря можно считать решением, а вот подсказкой, что помогла решить проблему -- да, вот про это и нужно написать в ответе :) Мол, выведя после loading понял, что неправильно <описание причины с правильным решением>. Кст, советую создавать поле словаря в `__init__` и обращаться к нему через `self.` (например: `self.my_dict = dict()`). Сейчас у вас создается в классе, а не у объекта, это разное и важное

Comment: А всё остальное так же остаётся, кроме я так понимаю когда добавляем кючи и значения Address.my_dict[ ] = ' ', надо потом писать self.my_dict?

Answer (score 0):

Я решил свой вопрос сам. После создания экземпляра пишем `Address.loading()`, ниже `print('Количество контактов - {} человек.'.format(len(Address.my_dict)))`, ниже `print(Address.my_dict)`. СМ. ниже часть изменённого кода.

```
r = Address('', '', '', '')
Address.loading()
print('Количество контактов - {} человек.'.format(len(Address.my_dict)))
print(Address.my_dict)
running = True
while running:
    try:
        search = int(input('Введите: 1-Добавить контакт; 2-Удалить контакт;\
 3-Изменить контакт; 4-Найти контакт;\
 Для выхода их программы введите 5-Выход: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Выберте один из варантов.')
    else:
        if search == 1:
            r.__setitem__('', '')
            if len(Address.my_dict) == 100:
                print('Адресная книга переполнена, удалите 1 из контактов')
                r.__delitem__('')

        if search == 2:
            try:
                r.__delitem__('')
            except KeyError:
                print('Вы ввели не верное имя.')

            Address.store()

        if search == 3:
            try:
                r.change()
            except KeyError:
                print('Введите существующее имя с заглавной буквы.')

            Address.store()

        if search == 4:
            try:
                r.find()
            except KeyError:
                print('Введите существующее имя с заглавной буквы.')

        if search == 5:
            Address.store()
            running = False

        if len(Address.my_dict) == 0:
            running = False
```

Аналоги магических методов пока не писал.